# Deleting carriage returns caused by line reading

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list:

```
Cat
Dog
Monkey
Pig
```

I have a script:

```
import sys
input_file = open('list.txt', 'r')
for line in input_file:
    sys.stdout.write('"' + line + '",')
```

The output is:

```
"Cat
","Dog
","Monkey
","Pig",
```

I'd like:

```
"Cat","Dog","Monkey","Pig",
```

I can't get rid of the carriage return that occurs from processing the lines in the list. Bonus point for getting rid of the , at the end. Not sure how to just find and delete the last instance.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

[str.rstrip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) or simply [str.strip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) is the right tool to split carriage return (newline) from the data read from the file. Note str.strip will strip of whitespaces from either end. If you are only interested in stripping of newline, just use `strip('\n')`

Change the line

```
 sys.stdout.write('"' + line + '",')
```

to

```
sys.stdout.write('"' + line.strip() + '",')
```

Note in your case, a more simplistic solution would had been

```
>>> from itertools import imap
>>> with open("list.txt") as fin:
    print ','.join(imap(str.strip, fin))


Cat,Dog,Monkey,Pig
```

or Just using List COmprehension

```
>>> with open("test.txt") as fin:
    print ','.join(e.strip('\n') for e in  fin)


Cat,Dog,Monkey,Pig
```

Comment: Why not include quotes like in the desired output?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [`.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove newlines from the right-hand side of a string:

```
line.rstrip('\n')
```

or you can tell it to remove *all* whitespace (including spaces, tabs and carriage returns):

```
line.rstrip()
```

It is a more specific version of the [`.strip()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) which removes whitespace or specific characters from *both* sides of the string.

For your *specific* case, you could stick with a simple `.strip()` but for the general case where you want to remove *only* the newline, I'd stick with `.rstrip('\n').

I'd use a different method to write your strings though:

```
with open('list.txt') as input_file:
    print ','.join(['"{}"'.format(line.rstrip('\n')) for line in input_file])
```

By using `','.join()` you avoid the last comma, and using the [`str.format()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is easier on the eyes than a lot of string concatenation (not to mention faster).

Comment: What is the format doing?  It seems to be passing the strings through unchanged.

Comment: @neil: Look again. There are single and double quotes.

Comment: Good point - I didn't notice that.  I didn't notice it in the question either so I now see my answer is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, in order to make it all appear on one line you should get rind of the `'\n'`.  I find `line.rstrip('\n')` to work nicely.

In order to get rid of the ',' at the end I would put all of the words in a list adding the quotation marks.  Then using join(), join all of the words in the list with ","

```
temp = []
for line in file:
    i = line.rstrip('\n')
    word = '"'+i+'"'
    temp.append(word)
print ",".join(temp)
```

That should get the desired output