# New column and column values get added to the next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I want to add a new column and new values to it. I'm just using normal file handling to do it (just adding a delimiter). I actually did try using csv but the csv file would have one letter per cell after running the code.

```
#import csv
#import sys

#csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)


inp = open("city2", "r")
inp2 = open("op", "r")
oup = open("op_mod.csv", "a+")





#alldata = []
count = 0 
for line in inp2:
  check = 0
  if count == 0:
    count = count + 1
    colline = line + "\t" + "cities"
    oup.write(colline)
    continue
  for city in inp:
    if city in line:
      print(city, line)
      linemod = line + "\t" + city #adding new value to an existing row
      #alldata.append(linemod)
      oup.write(linemod) #writing the new value
      check = 1
      break
  if check == 0:
    check = 1
    #oup.write(line)
    #alldata.append(line)
  inp.close()
  inp = open("city2", "r")

#writer.writerows(alldata)  
inp.close()
inp2.close()
oup.close()
```

Expected result:

```
existing fields/values ... new field/value
```

actual result:

```
existing fields/values ... new line
new field/value ...next line
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a carriage return at the end of line, you can remove it using line.rstrip() similar to this answer:
[Deleting carriage returns caused by line reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15007637/deleting-carriage-returns-caused-by-line-reading)

Comment: Are you sure? It might help if you show it by posting the solution in a block of code.